# Is there a word specific for "philosophy of philosophy" aside "metaphilosophy"?

Tags: terminology

I am pretty sure the word "metaphilosophy" is the only word for "philosophy of philosophy", but I wasn't quite sure it was the only word. Is there any other word that could be used as a synonym? Because you would think there would be other words, but upon trying to find related words, I couldn't find anything that matched the criteria.

Using a thesaurus, I got these:

hermeneutics    0.777966

gadamer    0.764499

epistemology    0.759714

intuitionism    0.756310

contextualism    0.745138

holism    0.742702

ricoeur    0.741946

hermeneutical    0.732353

rorty    0.729782

dialogism    0.723686

I am thinking there could be a word that meant "philosophy above philosophy" or some variant thereof that could have a similar meaning, but I couldn't find any such term. In law, you have the concept of "Law of laws", but I am wondering if there are similar concepts.

Comment: Metaphilosophy as Second-Order Philosophy https://medium.com/@paulaustinmurphy2000/metaphilosophy-examples-and-definitions-2f9947bf12b7

Comment: Martin Heidegger did believe in metaphilosophy (again, without using that term). He wrote:
“When we ask, ‘What is philosophy?’ then we are speaking about philosophy. By asking in this way we are obviously taking a stand above and, therefore, outside of philosophy.” https://medium.com/@paulaustinmurphy2000/metaphilosophy-examples-and-definitions-2f9947bf12b7

Comment: Metaphilosophy as outside of philosophy : Heidegger, therefore, seems to contradict himself. At first he says that metaphilosophy is “outside philosophy” and/or “above” philosophy. Then he says that his metaphilosophy has a
“direction [that] must at the same time give us the guarantee that we are moving within philosophy and not outside of it and around it”. https://medium.com/@paulaustinmurphy2000/metaphilosophy-examples-and-definitions-2f9947bf12b7

Comment: Perhaps Heidegger’s metaphilosophy is both above/beyond philosophy and “within philosophy” at one and the same time. https://medium.com/@paulaustinmurphy2000/metaphilosophy-examples-and-definitions-2f9947bf12b7

Comment: Where did you get those numbers from and what are they supposed to mean??

Answer (score 1):

The answer to your question is that there is really only one term, and it is [metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy). While some people reject its usage, note there is a journal that was founded in 1970 (50 years ago), and unsurprisingly, it's called [Metaphilsophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy_(journal)). The [SEP has at least one entry with the usage here](http://Latin%20American%20Philosophy:%20Metaphilosophical%20Foundations). The [IEP has an entry 'metaphilosophy'](https://iep.utm.edu/con-meta/). [Routledge has an entry too](https://www.rep.routledge.com/articles/biographical/rorty-richard-mckay-1931-2007/v-1/sections/metaphilosophy)!

So, if someone tells you your question is malformed, you might want to ask them to explain why no less than 4 online sources have entries with the term. If someone tells you that metaphilosophy doesn't mean anything, you might want to ask them how come there's at least 1 journal that has 50 years of publication devoted to the topic.

See, the problem with [rationalism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rationalism) it pays so little to what [really](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reality) happens. Rationalism is important, but it's value is lessened when it used to answer matters that are primarily [empirical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Empiricism) in nature. Some believe that [metaphilosophy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphilosophy) shouldn't be used, but that doesn't mean it isn't used. [Metaphysics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metaphysics) goes beyond physics, [metacommunication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-communication) is communication about communication, [metalangauges](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage) are languages about languages, and [meta-analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-analysis) is the act of analyzing analysis in some form. This [morpheme](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Morpheme) /MEta/ is so pragmatic for discourse [it has it's own entry](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta) which lists other examples and demonstrates an undeniable real linguistic practice. Compare also language [prescriptivism vs. descriptivism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linguistic_description).

So to reiterate, no, metaphilosophy is the best extant term and really has no synonyms. You have a good nose for questions!

Answer (score 0):

Being able to talk about the X of X doesn't mean talking about some higher thing by default. For example, "truth of truth," "fact of facts," "existence of existence," "God of God" (Nicenewise), "story of stories," "thinking of thinking," "love of love," don't necessarily seem to be "greater" than their base case, or an example of something beyond the base type. Philosophy of philosophy is like that: given what kinds of things are counted as philosophical, e.g. questions in mathematics, ethics, physics, politics, law, biology, theology, etc. a claim to go through a substantive "hyperphilosophy" to stand outside those questions completely would seem to otherwise look a lot like a philosophical claim, so what would be gained by an overly elevated hypercategory?

OTOH, there is also "history of philosophy" to consider. It is just an empirical fact, at least, that some philosophical arguments are more widely known than others, or have mostly been so over time in different ways, etc. The danger, if you will, here, is ending up with too strong a history of ideas, in the sense of an overly argumentative model of history vs. one hardly complete idea (to which the historian is beholden).

Edit: but to cite Kant, "transcendental philosophy" might count, as "how we know what philosophy is," in a way (how we recognize metaphysical and physical questions, say).

Comment: Intereseting view. By convention, [meta-](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta) is a prefix to do precisely just that, though 'beyond' might be a better translation than 'above'. [Metacommunication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta-communication) is communication that goes beyond communication, because it ABOUT communication..

Comment: Then is it possible just by use of a prefix to construct the validity or reality of this beyond, as if we spoke of metatruth, even though, "Metatruth is greater than truth," would have to be true, so beyond truth would depend on truth, which seems pointless? Also, where do we stop? In principle, there is n-order logic, not only for all n, but also for all transfinite ordinals. Would we not speak of a philosophy of metaphilosophy, even, then? "Philosophy of" is itself a lot like "meta-" as a qualifier in the first place.

Comment: Well, adding a prefix to a word doesn't give it reality unless it is adopted by speakers. Generally speaking, language prescriptivism is ineffective. Adding the morpheme as a prefix, however, does constitute a rule as it gives a hint to the meaning of the extended concept. Whether or not you reject the usage, it's widespread. Another perfectly legitimate example is a meta-analysis: an analysis of analyses. Would meta-truth be pointless? I don't know that the term has any currency, but in formal systems of language...

Comment: one must differentiate between a language and a [metalanguage](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Metalanguage). (Hee hee.) A meta-truth were it to be adopted would easily be a true statement in the metalanguage as opposed to a truth in the object language. N-order? Well, there are pragmatic limits to repeating a morpheme and keeping the meaning of the term in mind, but certainly we can agree that were there to be a journal calle Metacommunication, and one were to conduct a meta-analysis of the studies in it, one could discuss the methodology of metacommunication studies. Thus meta-metacomm...

Comment: Well you get the idea. I reject that the philosophy of biology is equivalent to metabiology. The former is an extant body of literature, but the latter is meaningless. One couldn't have metabiology on the basis that the biology of biology doesn't have meaning. What metacommuncation, metalanguage, metaphysics, and meta-analysis have in common is they're all examples of the application of discourse to examine that same form of discourse. Thus,meta seems to me to be constrained in usage.

Comment: Is a second-order example of a concept an example of a different enough concept to count such that metaphilosophy is "higher" than philosophy, though? I guess that's where my confusion lies.

Comment: That is a value-laden metaphysical conception, is it not? Empirically there are two camps, for and against. What justification can be offered for accepting or rejecting? What does it mean to be literally "different enough" or metaphorically "higher and lower", or "beyond"? If you were asked the question, is philosophy and philosophy about the methodology of philosophy different enough to warrant a distinct term for the latter, how would one even go about answering? A speaker would save breath, and a printer ink, but under what conditions generally is new coinage circulated?

Comment: I don't think you're confused. I think you want a simple rule to determine when a [technical neologism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Neologism) is warranted and when it is not, and that's not something that is readily prescribed. Mightn't a lifetime of being taught what the "rules" of English should be undermine the notion that language is an erratic democratic institution more subject to distributed psychological whim rather than centralized rational intent? [Beware of mavens who prescribe language!](https://newrepublic.com/article/77732/grammar-puss-steven-pinker-language-william-safire).

Comment: A counterargument is always welcome!

Answer (score -1):

There is a book with the title "*The philosophy of philosophy*":

> "*Likewise, the primary task of the philosophy of philosophy is to understand philosophy, not to give philosophers advice - although I have not vigorously abstained from the latter.*" -- Timothy Williamson, The Philosophy of Philosophy (2008)

So, a philosopher doesn't feel the need to use any other expression than "*the philosophy of philosophy*".

Maybe he decided that nobody would understand another expression to mean "philosophy of philosophy".

Yes, the only expression that means "philosophy of philosophy" is the expression "philosophy of philosophy" itself.

A dictionary would have told you that.